# Problem with assigning string into struct array in c

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am not very skilled at C, especially the dynamic allocation bit of C and I´ve encountered this strange problem. Background is that I have to read input from a user, save it into struct that I defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int camera_ID;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int min;
    char rz[1001];
} cameraEntry;
```

and then save that struct into an array. Everything works fine, I am able to read the data, create said struct but when it comes to saving it into the array it crashes. I´ve tried assignign the values one by one and found out that the char array causes problems. I´ve tried assigning it char by char but there must be something else I am missing. Here is the code for reading and saving the user input and my main function:

```
int readEntry(cameraEntry **entries, int *maxN)
{
    int n = 0, last = 0;
    char brace;
    *entries = malloc(*maxN * sizeof(cameraEntry *));
    if (scanf("%c", &brace) != 1 || brace != '{')
        return -1;
    do 
    {
        if (n >= *maxN)
        {
            *maxN = *maxN * 2;
            *entries = realloc(*entries, *maxN * sizeof(cameraEntry *));
        }
        cameraEntry read = parseInput(&last);
        if (read.camera_ID < 0)
            return -1;
        (*entries)[n].camera_ID = read.camera_ID;
        (*entries)[n].month = read.month;
        (*entries)[n].day = read.day;
        (*entries)[n].hour = read.hour;
        (*entries)[n].min = read.min;
        
        //Without this line of code it works like charm
        strcpy((*entries)[n].rz, read.rz);
        n++;
    } while (last == 0);    
    return n;   
}

int main(void)
{
    cameraEntry *entries = NULL;
    int maxN = 2;   
    int n = readEntry(&entries, &maxN);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input\n");
        free(entries);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Entry count: %d\n", n);
    free(entries);
    return 0;
}
```

So please, if you can find the mistake in my code and explain why is it happening I would be very grateful.

Comment: Change `sizeof(cameraEntry *)` to `sizeof(cameraEntry)` in the `malloc` and `realloc` calls.

Comment: And `(*entries)[n] = read;` is a lot simpler.  You can assign `struct` values...

Comment: @kaylum Thank you very much! Can´t believe I actually missed that. Problem solved.